# Selecting a specific child element in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that can occur up to 8 times on a page so adding in ID's into the objects is not a solution. I need to enable the submit button when the 2 fields are the same.
I cannot think of a way to do it. please can you help me?

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass1">New Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass1" placeholder="Pa55word">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass2">Retype Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass2" placeholder="Pa55word">
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" name="subpass" class="btn btn-primary disabled" value="go" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('form input[type="password"]').keyup(function () {
if($(this.???)){
   $(this.???)removeClass('disabled')
}
});
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3uURp/1/)

Comment: You can compare the input's values. Retrieve them via `$(this).val()` or (non-jQuery) `this.value`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3uURp/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('form input[type="password"]').keyup(function () {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  if(form.find('input[type="password"]').first().val() === 
     form.find('input[type="password"]').last().val()){
    form.find('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled'); //or remove class
  } else {
    form.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', ''); //disable the button
  }
});
```

Here is an example in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3uURp/3/

And here is how it works with few forms at once http://jsfiddle.net/3uURp/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3uURp/5/ <-- this method dosen't work when I have multiple forms

Comment: It works, you just had some invalid markup. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/3uURp/6/

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
$('form input[type="password"]').keyup(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.closest("div");
    if( $this.val() == $this.closest("form").find("div.form-group").not($parent).find("input").val() ){
       console.log("equals");
    } else {
        console.log("not equals");
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xUkU3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/379rj/):

```
$('form input[type="password"]').keyup(function () {
  var form = $(this).closest('form')
  var pass1 = form.find('input[name=pass1]')
  var pass2 = form.find('input[name=pass2]')
  var submit = form.find('input[type=submit]')

  var condition = pass1.val().length == 0 || (pass1.val() != pass2.val())
  submit.attr("disabled", condition)
});
```

Comment: It should work. The problem is that there is a wrong and missing </div>. see: http://jsfiddle.net/379rj/2/